# How to get email form submissions script to exclude blank response values from sheet?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am editing an existing script that my team uses for a google form response sheet. The script automatically creates a message body using the headers and response cells for an order every time it is submitted, roughly like this:

Type of Order: Physical
Country: America
Digital Signature:
Favorite Color: 
Favorite Food: Pasta

What I've been asked to do, is have the script read through the sheet and not include the header or response for questions that are not answered in any given submission. Like so, for the previous example:

Type of Order: Physical
Country: America
Favorite Food: Pasta

I should start by saying I have close to 0 experience in javascript or Google Apps. I have tried playing around with if clauses using both the len function and a negated isblank function to no avail. These all lead to undefined errors.

As you'll see, the original script was not created by me or the people who have been using it for the last few years.

```
Original script

function sendFormByEmail(e) 
{ 
  Logger.log('value of e is: ' + e);   
  var email = "xxx@xxx.com"; 

  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
  var message = "";
  var subject = "Type A Request: ";

  // The variable e holds all the form values in an array.
  // Loop through the array and append values to the body.   

  // Insert variables from the spreadsheet into the subject.
  // In this case, I wanted the new hire's name and start date in the
  // email subject. These are the 3rd and 16th columns in my form.

for(var i in headers) 
  message += headers[i] + ': '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n";     

  subject += e.namedValues[headers[10]].toString() + " - " + 
  e.namedValues[headers[12]].toString();


  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {noReply:true}); 

    // Based off of a script originally posted by Amit Agarwal - www.labnol.org
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include a check for blank values inside the for loop.

```
 if (e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() === "") continue;
```